# автозагрузка классов для плагина WP

Tags: php, wordpress-плагины, autoload

Пишу плагин для WP, хочу в нем реализовать автозагрузку своих классов, использую для этого `spl_autoload_register()` структура плагина такова:

[image: скрин структуры плагина]

автозагрузчик выглядит так

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    $plugin_dir =  plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);
    $str = $plugin_dir.$class_name . '.php';
    $str = str_replace("\\", "/", $str);
    require_once ($str);
});
```

Вот код главного файла плагина

```
<?php
require_once "authoload.php";
use Core\Controllers\App;
/**
 * Plugin Name: Discounts
 * Description: Discounts desc
 * Plugin URI:  webazex.com
 * Author URI:  webazex.com
 * Author:      webazex.com
 * Version:     Версия плагина, например 0.1
 *
 * Text Domain: discounts
 * Domain Path: /lang
 *
 * License:     GPL2
 * License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 *
 * Network:    true
 */
App::start();
```

Получаю следующее:

[image: скрин]
Судя по скрину.

Мой класс загружается, все ок, но почему-то также туда попадают и все остальные классы, хотя по идее автозагрузчик должен искать только те классы которые я вызываю в файле где он подключен. Как сделать так чтобы подгружались через автозагрузчик только мои классы?

Comment: есть отличная статья по автозагрузке https://www.kobzarev.com/programming/autoload/

Comment: понял, попробую реализовать